# LP-BT63 headset left speaker and mic not working

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I've bought this extremely high end headset that plays nicely with Android but less nicely with Ubuntu (20.04). I can pair it, it goes in A2DP Sink mode but I hear only the right channel. The left channel and the mic don't work.

`dmesg` just says:

```
[Fri Oct 15 21:32:41 2021] input: LP-BT63 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input18
[Fri Oct 15 21:57:46 2021] input: LP-BT63 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input19
```

Any idea how to debug/fix this thing?

[image: extremely-high-end-headset]

Comment: Correct the profile you have chosen will not give you the mic. You should be getting both channels on the sound so a different problem.

Comment: Yep, it doesn't even show the AVRCP profile ¯\_(ツ)_/¯